# heroku java spring mvc hibernate app suddenly not able to access postgres db

Tags: postgresql, heroku, spring-data-jpa, javabeans, hibernate-mapping

I had an heroku app has been running on there for the pass 5 years, and I have not doing any deployment for a while.
Only recently I saw there were two auto update by heroku postgres addon itself
[image]

Then from today, I try to go to my app as usual, try to do login, but failed as the app error log is saying not able to connect to postgres DB anymore. Please see these error, and my spring bean setting for DB connection (this setting has been there for 5 years unchanged, suddenly all stop working...)
[image]

I am wondering has anyone else encountered this issue recently? is it due to heroku major upgrade?
Please advise an solution  if possible
Thanks

=================================================================

I have attached error log here:

```
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688282+00:00 app[web.1]: Feb 26, 2021 5:18:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688302+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection] with root cause
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688304+00:00 app[web.1]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "35.175.150.172", user "hazpvnhqxtodzl", database "d7fhtbev11bt6m", SSL off
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688305+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688306+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688307+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688307+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688308+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688308+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688308+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688309+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688310+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688311+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688311+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688312+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688312+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688313+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688313+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688314+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688316+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688316+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688317+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688317+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688318+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688318+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688318+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688319+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688320+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:61)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688320+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688321+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688321+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688322+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688322+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688323+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688323+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688324+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.listTillReportHistory(Unknown Source)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688324+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.lsinternal.restfulservice.ApiTill.reportTillHistory(ApiTill.java:75)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688325+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688325+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688326+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688326+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688333+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688335+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688336+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688337+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688337+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:672)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688338+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:82)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688338+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688339+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688339+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688340+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688340+00:00 app[web.1]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688341+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688341+00:00 app[web.1]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688342+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688342+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
2021-02-26T17:18:50.688343+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
```

Also, the config of my DB connection in spring xml config file:

```
  <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
        <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() + '?sslmode=require' }"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
        <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

it is absolutely identical to this tutorial -> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#spring-xml

I have been trying to solve the issue in the pass 3 days, really ran out of idea now... please advise if possible
Thanks

Comment: Actually after nearly half months digging, it is issue with java 7 to java 8 upgrading things. please see   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66628051/heroku-upgrading-spring-app-from-java-7-to-java-8-encountered-java-util-mapentr  this post, this setup resolves JDBC connection issue with heroku postgres , but still having issue with JSP rendering... if anyone could advise, please jump to this post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this one](https://help.heroku.com/DR0TTWWD/seeing-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-errors-in-postgres):

> ### Seeing "FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry" errors in Postgres
>
> ### Issue
>
> I'm seeing "no pg_hba.conf entry for host" errors:
>
> ```
> sql_error_code = 28000 FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "122.180.247.11", user "u3idolso5k2v83", database "dc85788d13v9ej", SSL off
> ```
>
> ### Resolution
>
> "FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host" errors indicate that there was a failed authentication attempt to the database, so the connection couldn't be established. This can happen because of different reasons:

> - The authentication failed because the user/password credentials were invalid: ((user "xxxx", database "yyyy")). This could happen if you're trying to connect to the database using wrong or revoked credentials. (See also: [Why am I seeing connection errors for my Heroku Postgres database from an unexpected IP address?](https://help.heroku.com/QVRZIEAH/why-am-i-seeing-connection-errors-for-my-heroku-postgres-database-from-an-unexpected-ip-address-what-are-these-unauthorized-connection-attempts)).

> - The authentication failed because the connection didn't use SSL encryption: (**SSL off**). [All Heroku Postgres production databases require using SSL connections](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#heroku-postgres-ssl) to ensure that communications between applications and the database remain secure. If your client is not using SSL to connect to your database, you would see these errors even if you're using the right credentials to connect to it.

"I think" here **SSL OFF** is the case/(at least also) true. (Please rather copy&paste logs, than screen-shoting 'em!)

-> ([2](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#heroku-postgres-ssl)):

> Most clients will connect over SSL by default, but on occasion it is necessary to set the `sslmode=require` parameter on a Postgres connection. **Please add this parameter in code rather than editing the config var directly**. Please check you are enforcing use of SSL especially if you are using Java or Node.js clients.
>
> ...
>
> **It is also important that you use a version of the Postgres JDBC driver verion 9.2 or greater**. For example, in Maven add this to your pom.xml:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
>   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
>   <version>42.2.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> - The `DATABASE_URL` for the Heroku Postgres add-on follows this naming convention:
>
>   ```
>    postgres://<username>:<password>@<host>/<dbname>
>   ```
> - However the Postgres JDBC driver uses the following convention:
>
>   ```
>   jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?sslmode=require&user=<username>&password=<password>
>   ```

Comment: Hi xerx, I have just edit my post with code snapshot,  really ran out of idea now, wish you could still help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to your `Database Credentials` in your panel, Heroku says:

> Please note that these credentials are **not** permanent. Heroku rotates
> credentials periodically and updates applications where this database
> is attached.

I recommend you check your credentials again, maybe it has changed.