# heroku upgrading spring app from java 7 to java 8 encountered java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to upgrade an spring mvc app from java 7 to 8 on heroku
My setup is as follow:

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate-template</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <version>42.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.34.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>newrelic-agent</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dropbox.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropbox-core-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.turo</groupId>
            <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
          <!--<dependency>-->
             <!--<groupId>com.notnoop.apns</groupId>-->
             <!--<artifactId>apns</artifactId>-->
             <!--<version>1.0.0.Beta6</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0.34.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                          <id>copy-new-relic</id>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                     <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>com.newrelic.agent.java</includeGroupIds>
                            <includeArtifactIds>newrelic-agent</includeArtifactIds>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

system.properties:

```
java.runtime.version=1.8
```

and in /WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Spring-Hibernate-Template

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/rest-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/rest-dispatcher-servlet-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>503</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

And then finally my spring config xml  (dispatcher-servlet.xml)

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject" />

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="jspViewResolverForBusiness" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/business/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>

<!-- Task excutor -->
<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- Tiles configuration -->
<bean id="tilesviewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver"/>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

</bean>

<beans profile="default">
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource"/>        
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="prod">
    <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
        <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() + '?sslmode=require' }"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
        <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And I can confirm some part of the app is running fine, e.g some restful json endpoints (they do response correct json data)
But any JSP page render is dead...  the error log looks like this:

: at

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.329301+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.329302+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369622+00:00 app[web.1]: Mar 14, 2021 6:07:52 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1 findType
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369623+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Compilation error
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369624+00:00 app[web.1]: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369625+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369625+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:231)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369626+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:187)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369626+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:113)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369629+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369630+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)

]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369644+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369644+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369644+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.369645+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518809+00:00 app[web.1]: Mar 14, 2021 6:07:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518811+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518812+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518813+00:00 app[web.1]: An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518813+00:00 app[web.1]: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518814+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518814+00:00 app[web.1]: An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518815+00:00 app[web.1]: The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518815+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518816+00:00 app[web.1]: Stacktrace:] with root cause
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518816+00:00 app[web.1]: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518816+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518817+00:00 app[web.1]: An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518818+00:00 app[web.1]: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518818+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518818+00:00 app[web.1]: An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518819+00:00 app[web.1]: The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518819+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518820+00:00 app[web.1]: Stacktrace:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518820+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518821+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518821+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518822+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518822+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518822+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518823+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)

]: at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518832+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518832+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518832+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518833+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518833+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.518834+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720440+00:00 app[web.1]: Mar 14, 2021 6:07:52 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1 findType
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720458+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Compilation error
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720459+00:00 app[web.1]: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720459+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720460+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:231)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720460+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:187)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720461+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:113)

: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720498+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720499+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720499+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720500+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.720500+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-14T18:07:52.808532+00:00 app[web.1]: Mar 14, 2021 6:07:52 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1 findType
2021-03-14T18:07:52.808535+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Compilation error
2021-03-14T18:07:52.808535+00:00 app[web.1]: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
2021-03-14T18:07:52.808536+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.808537+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:231)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.808537+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:187)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.808538+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:113)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.808539+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.808540+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
2021-03-14T18:07:52.808540+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:168)
```

So I assume it is something to do with java 8 env problem?  But on heroku,  I believe the tomcat version is 9 by default https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1724
But I do not know how to actually check my tomcat version using heroku cli, anyone got idea?

Or does it looks like heroku tomcat issue?  If so, which version of tomcat should I use?
Please advise
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try upgrading the web-runner dependency to 9.0.27.1? Currently it is set to,

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.34.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Gedam,  thanks for the advise, it works, so I updated to <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
      <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
      <version>8.5.47.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>  you saved my life, haha :)